# Find the child of the next silbling in selenium java using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to send keys to a text field called Last Name.

```
<div style="height: 40px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 150px;"> 
  <div class="v-caption" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <div class="v-captiontext">Last Name</div>
    <div class="v-required-field-indicator">*</div>
    <div class="v-caption-clearelem"/>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;">
    <input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-required" style="width: 144px;"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am able to find the Last Name by using getText feature. What is the cleanest way to get the text field which is the child of the sibling of Last Name ? We use Vaadin to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are expecting as the result. You say:

> What is the cleanest way to get the text field which is the child of the sibling of Last Name ?

But it seems that you are not trying to find a sibling of the `div` element that contains "Last Name", but a sibling of its parent. I also assume that by "text field" you mean an `input` element. Please try

```
//div[div = 'Last Name']/following-sibling::div[1]/input
```

which will return

```
<input type="text" class="v-textfield v-textfield-required" style="width: 144px;"/>
```

Comment: The input field in Java translates to two divs. One containing the label and the other the actual text field(input element). I locate the the "combined" field by label and then populate the input element by locating it as the next sibling's child.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a full css selector with Selenium to find whathever you want =)

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table tbody tr"));
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this specific question. It only states that CSS selectors can be used in Selenium, but not how to find what the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath:-

```
//div[@class='v-captiontext' and //div[contains(@class,'v-captiontext')] and contains(.,'Last Name')]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp) of xpath

```
//div[text()='Last Name']/following-sibling::div/input
```

but I recommend you to use this:

```
//div[./div[text()='Last Name']]//input
```

Comment: Both XPath expressions are incorrect and do not select anything in this document snippet. The problem also has nothing to do with XPath axes in particular.

Answer (score 0):

with whatever I can see, I came up with following.

//div[@class='v-captiontext']

I used the //tagname[@attribute='value'] syntax to come up with Xpath.